# How to constrain the keys of a TypeScript object while inferring the values?

Tags: typescript

Often times, when I have a union of string literals in TypeScript, I want to create a map from the strings to other values. This involved creating a type that doesn't let the values infer which can be annoying when I want to access the value types as well. For example, here's a basic hangup:

```
type UserPersona =
    | "entrepreneur"
    | "programmer"
    | "designer"
    | "product_manager"
    | "marketing_sales"
    | "customer_support"
    | "operations_hr"


const userPersonaDisplayNames: { [key in UserPersona]: string } = {
    entrepreneur: "Entrepreneur",
    programmer: "Programmer",
    designer: "Designer",
    product_manager: "Product Manager",
    marketing_sales: "Marketing & Sales",
    customer_support: "Customer Support",
    operations_hr: "Operations & HR",
}
```

The problem here is that the values of `userPersonaDisplayNames` are type `string` and not their literal values.

When I leave off the type, the keys and and values are literal types which is great, but the keys are no longer constrained to the union type.

```
const userPersonaDisplayNames = {
    entrepreneur: "Entrepreneur",
    programmer: "Programmer",
    designer: "Designer",
    product_manager: "Product Manager",
    marketing_sales: "Marketing & Sales",
    customer_support: "Customer Support",
    operations_hr: "Operations & HR",
}
```

One hack I've discovered is to use extends to assert.

```
type Assert<A,B> = A extends B

type assertPersonaKeys = Assert<keyof userPersonaDisplayNames, UserPersona>
```

This works, but it's kind of gross. I have an unused type laying around that TSLint complains about.

It seems like the `infer` keyword is exactly what I'm looking for, but I'm not sure how it works and it doesn't work in my case. Ideally I could do something like this:

```
const userPersonaDisplayNames: { [key in UserPersona]: infer } = {
    entrepreneur: "Entrepreneur",
    programmer: "Programmer",
    designer: "Designer",
    product_manager: "Product Manager",
    marketing_sales: "Marketing & Sales",
    customer_support: "Customer Support",
    operations_hr: "Operations & HR",
}
```

Any ideas how to solve this problem in a clean way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a helper function to represent the constraint you want to see and then call it?  There is a very small amount of runtime overhead, since it's calling `(t => t)(obj)` instead of just using `obj`.

```
const asUserPersonaDisplayNames = <
  S extends string, // allow S to be inferred as a string literal
  T extends Record<UserPersona, S> & // require keys from UserPersona
  Record<Exclude<keyof T, UserPersona>, never> // disallow keys not from UserPersona
>(t: T) => t

const userPersonaDisplayNames = asUserPersonaDisplayNames({
  entrepreneur: "Entrepreneur",
  programmer: "Programmer",
  designer: "Designer",
  product_manager: "Product Manager",
  marketing_sales: "Marketing & Sales",
  customer_support: "Customer Support",
  operations_hr: "Operations & HR",
}); // type has fully string-literal values

const missing = asUserPersonaDisplayNames({
  entrepreneur: "Entrepreneur",
  programmer: "Programmer",
  product_manager: "Product Manager",
  marketing_sales: "Marketing & Sales",
  customer_support: "Customer Support",
  operations_hr: "Operations & HR",
}) // error, property "designer" is missing

const extra = asUserPersonaDisplayNames({
  candlestick_maker: "Rub a Dub Dub",
  entrepreneur: "Entrepreneur",
  programmer: "Programmer",
  designer: "Designer",
  product_manager: "Product Manager",
  marketing_sales: "Marketing & Sales",
  customer_support: "Customer Support",
  operations_hr: "Operations & HR",
}); // error, property "candlestick_maker" is extra

const notString = asUserPersonaDisplayNames({
  entrepreneur: 25,
  programmer: "Programmer",
  designer: "Designer",
  product_manager: "Product Manager",
  marketing_sales: "Marketing & Sales",
  customer_support: "Customer Support",
  operations_hr: "Operations & HR",
}); // error, number is not expected
```

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Have you written a TS book yet? I'd buy it in a flash.